# Excel 2019. I have a fee in column A that depends on a balance in column B

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a fee in column A that depends on a balance in column B. But the fee is worked out on several different number ranges. E.g., if the balance in column B is between 7K and 14K then the fee is 25%. If balance is between 14K and 50K then fee is 20%. I have 8 different ranges.

Any idea how to write a formula for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title says Excel 2019, the tag says 2010. The answers are different for both versions. Using all the below the result looks like this:

[image]

---

**Excel 2010**
Nested `IF`

```
=IF(B2<7000,B2*30%,IF(B2<14000,B2*25%,IF(B2<50000,B2*20%,B2*15%)))
```

**Excel 2019**
`IFS`

```
=IFS(B2<7000,B2*30%,B2<14000,B2*25%,B2<50000,B2*20%,TRUE,B2*15%)
```

`SWITCH`

```
=SWITCH(TRUE,B2<7000,B2*30%,B2<14000,B2*25%,B2<50000,B2*20%,B2*15%)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest putting the fee ranges in a separate Worksheet where the first column contains the start of the balance range and the second column contains the corresponding fee. The ranges must be in ascending order from start value:

[image]

Then, in the main Worksheet use `VLOOKUP` to search for the corresponding fee. The trick is to use `TRUE` on the last parameter.

```
VLOOKUP(B2,Aux!$A:$B,2,TRUE)
```

[image]

This way, you have flexibility when changing ranges and fees and, as far as I know, will work on any Excel version.

Comment: That's brilliant thanks